# Software Center on Ubuntu 16.04 is Constantly Loading - Unable to Use

Tags: 16.04, software-center

Software Center, now just called "Software", is constantly loading and not displaying any updates or searched packages. The apt-get command is working just fine, but it seems to be stuck. Perhaps a recent update requires a reboot?

Comment: This issue is still present. I tried using Software today to upgrade and the "Install" button at the top does not install everything. The "Install" buttons next to each item also appear to do nothing, and it locks the admin directory for dpkg. So essentially it's not working and interfering with software that does work.

Answer (score 28):

On Ubuntu 20.04, I killed the `snap-store` process (`pkill snap-store` - thanks [Luckylooke](https://askubuntu.com/users/229005/luckylooke)), and everything started working. No need for a re-start.

Comment: Thank you @alikelzin-kilaka. For beginners: run `pkill snap-store` in your terminal window. Store downloaded new catalogue and it started to work 

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt purge gnome-software ubuntu-software
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install gnome-software ubuntu-software
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem recently, but i came out with ending gnome-software task and then starting it up again. And it worked for me.

You can do this by using System Monitor.

Comment: Worked with ubuntu 20.04 - process name was `snap-store` in my case

Comment: Worked with Zorin 16 - Focal based